# What does scipy.ndimage.morphology.grey_dilation for an even size structuring element?

Tags: python, scipy, image-morphology

A question about morphological operation

Suppose I have the following input image  (called I):

```
array([[  1,   2,   3,   4],
       [  5,   6,   7,   8],
       [  9, 100,   6,   7],
       [  9,   8,   7,   9]])
```

I want then to make a grey scale dilation with a squared structuring element of size 3*3 here is the command to call :

```
structuring_element = np.zeros((3,3))
I_max = grey_dilation(I, structure=structuring_element)
```

Here is the result :

```
array([[  6,   7,   8,   8],
       [100, 100, 100,   8],
       [100, 100, 100,   9],
       [100, 100, 100,   9]])
```

Which seems to be logical, but now suppose I will do the same with a 2x2 structuring_element :

```
structuring_element = np.zeros((2,2))
I_max = grey_dilation(I, structure=structuring_element)
```

Here is the new outcome :

```
array([[  6,   7,   8,   8],
       [100, 100,   8,   8],
       [100, 100,   9,   9],
       [  9,   8,   9,   9]])
```

Can someone explain me what is the function performing when having as input an even sized structuring element?

Comment: Since there is no array element that corresponds to the center for an even sized structuring element, why not use the lower right one of the four. Try (4, 4) or (3, 2), (3, 4), (3, 6) to see that this is consistent.

Comment: I guess it will probably be the upper left instead of the lower right, since we have a 6 for the pixel (0,0) of the resulting image ?

Comment: No. Dilation is from the center to the periphery. Look at the [examples in the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.grey_dilation.html), if you don't want to experiment with the examples given by me.

Comment: Ah ok so you mean that the center of a 2 by 2 shape will by one of the four  and same for the center of a 4 by 4 structuring element, it will be one a the four in the middle?

Comment: Yes. And it will be the right/lower element, if there is no element exactly in the middle.

Comment: Ok, but not sure for the location of this approximate center.
Suppose we take the lower right pixel of a 2 by 2 shape as the center, the first line of I_max in my question, will not be [6, 7, 8, 8]  but [1, 2, 3, 4] as in the original image?

Comment: @Fou: That depends on how they define the dilation. In MrT's way, you'd take the SE, place it on a pixel, read the value at the origin, and write that to all other pixels in the SE (taking the max with the value already there). In your way, you'd take the SE, place it on a pixel, look for the max value under the SE, and write it to the pixel at the origin. These are equivalent, except the SE is mirrored.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I understand your answer but the think is that I didn't how they perform for even sized SE, I mean, which pixels will they take in the neighborhood to pick the max.

Comment: @Fou: This is what I'm saying, what the actual neighborhood looks like depends on the definition of the dilation that they're using. Both definitions are equally valid. To know what a specific implementation does, simply do the experiment as you did and see what the result is. :)

Comment: Ok, the main problem is that it was a bit annoying to perform many tests in order to understand the logical behind it ...